# WMAppManifest.xml is missing from Windows Phone 8.1 Apps building

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Recently I have upgraded `Visual Studio 2013 update 2`. There are lot of changes in this huge update and one among this update is `Windows Phone 8.1 Apps` you can start building now.

Currently I am developing an apps for which I need to configure certain value in `WMAppManifest.xml` file. Even in MSDN says that the file is under `Properties` but I could not find any. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769509(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Amazingly this entire file is missing and the value I want to change is not there any more. 
Has anybody faced this issue and ay work around of how to find out the location of this file? Is it renamed. 
I googled but failed to get what I was looking at. If anybody guide me that will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `WMAppManifest.xml` file is only for Silverlight app and my guess is you created a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML app. The file you need is `Package.appxmanifest`, it contains more or less the same settings as  `WMAppManifest.xml`  used for Silverlight apps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but previously if I am not wrong in windows phone 8 project too we have `WMAppManifest.xml` file. At least that's what the msdn link says. Still unable to figure out how come this is missing. How come MSDN link is wrong in this aspect.

Comment: "Applies to: Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 only"

Comment: Thanks for the information. I checked with `Visual Studio 2013` and found that there are two ways you can start developing Apps for `Windows Phone 8.1`. 1 is `Universal Apps` and 2 is `Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight)`. In the second options `WMAppManifest.xml` comes as said MSDN but not in the first place. Still unable to figure out what's the purpose of this two way to build apps. A confused approach I would say.

Comment: Silverlight has been here since WP7, WP8 so it is still supported in 8.1. The 8.1 XAML (part of universal apps) is the new way to do 8.1 apps. Microsoft likes to reinvent the wheel.